# ajax function goes to error though it goes to my webservice

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

```
<script type='text/javascript'> 
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var userName = $("#username").val();
        var pwd = $("#password").val();
        authenticate(userName, pwd);
    });
});

function authenticate(userName, pwd) {
    var serviceurl = "http://localhost:8080/Authentication/rest/authentication/info";
    $.ajax({
        url: serviceurl + '/' + userName + '/' + pwd,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        async: true,
        crossDomain: true,
        jsonp: 'callback',
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback',
        success: function () {
            alert("Web service call succeeded.");
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert('ERROR has occurred!');
            alert(JSON.stringify(error))
        }
    })
} 
</script>
```

I got the folllowing result when on submitting

```
Request URL:url/Authentication/rest/authentication/info/0009/Aipl@2009?callback=jsonpCallback&_=1398314791025
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:8080
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/33.0.1750.154 Safari/537.36
Query String Parametersview sourceview URL encoded
callback:jsonpCallback
_:1398314791025
Response Headersview source
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS, HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Content-Type:application/json
Date:Thu, 24 Apr 2014 04:46:34 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

i can see my json data in response

Comment: i even ttried writing jsonpCallback function with just an alert in script but still it didnt work..

Answer (score 0):

I bet the page isn't being *served from* `http://localhost:8080`.  If not, you are committing a cross-site scripting violation.

**edit:**  No, the cross-site scripting headers are there.  Are you sending a header other than Content-Type, Accept, and X-Requested-With?

**edit:**  More wild guessing: your server isn't set up to do JSONP at all.  The data returned from a JSONP should look like this

```
jsonpCallback({"user":"3349997","iq":120})
```

Or whatever.  If it is just the data

```
{"user":"3349997","iq":120}
```

Then you should strip out all the JSONP stuff and handle it as (much more reliable) JSON.

**edit:** correct answer, strip out all the JSONP stuff and change it from a POST to GET.

Comment: what am i supposed to do??

Comment: Look at the data actually being returned.  Is it legit Javascript?  It should begin with `jsonpCallback({...`.  Given that you have all the cross-site stuff there, why are you screwing with JSONP (which sucks) at all?

Comment: with out jsonp its returning 405 method not allowed error

Comment: What does the *data* it returns (with the JSONP) look like?

Comment: @Malvolio you're right, the serverside is at fault here. I made a JSFiddle with JSONP and code works. http://jsfiddle.net/tBMS8/

Comment: {"projects":[{"projectID":"AIOFSRR11","projectName":"ReMG_Offsite Resource Request"},{"projectID":"AITSAD11","projectName":"ReMG_Timesheet Allocation & DeAllocation"},{"projectID":"AICRDC07","projectName":"City of Richmond"},{"projectID":"AIITIS08","projectName":"IT SUPPORT"},{"projectID":"DLM3LeakVa","projectName":"Leak Validation"},{"projectID":"AISGDC09","projectName":"Socal Gas"},{"projectID":"AIITSS08","projectName":"Online Problem Reporting Syste"},{"projectID":"AIPGDC12","projectName":"PG & E"}]}

Comment: so do you think i have to change my webservice code??

Comment: Mmmm, you just have to figure something out, and you are almost there..  That *isn't* JSONP, it's plain JSON.  You have to figure a way to get that response (which is perfectly legit), without making the client expect JSONP.  Have you tried `dataType: 'json'` ?

Comment: yes with json i am getting 405 method not allowed error

Comment: You are going to have to carefully evaluate the `difference` between what the browser sends with 'jsonp' and 'json' and figure out what is causing that error.  If worse comes to worst, put "?callback=jsonpCallback" directly in the URL (so your messed-up server won't give you the 405), but tell the client it is "json", so it doesn't try to evaluate the result.

Comment: finally got it worked changed my code as
type:'GET',
datatype:'json' 

IT WORKED!!!! 
 THANK U @Malvolio and limelights

Comment: GET?  Mwahaha.  I should have guessed that.  JSONP is always a GET; when you stop specifying JSONP, the Ajax library reverted to the method you named.  Amazing how simple these things are in retrospect.

Comment: @Malvolio can plz tell me how to present my data in ajax sucess function.. have given my json data in above comments

Comment: For example `success: function (d) {alert(d.projects[0].projectID); }` will pop up "AIOFSRR11".